# Unclaimed Network in Ubuntu 14.04.5

Tags: networking, wireless, broadcom

I cannot get WIFI connections on the applet. I think when I have upgraded to 14.04.5 and also autoremoved previous kernels versions, after a restart  this issue has begun , since this was working before.

Attaching wireless-info

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 30 Aug 2017 13:26 IST +0530

Booted last: 30 Aug 2017 11:56 IST +0530

Script from: 25 Mar 2017 07:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.13.0-129-generic #178-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 11 12:48:20 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]

09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0558]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:6473 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 0781:5567 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Blade
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

##### lsmod #############################

dell_wmi               12761  0 
sparse_keymap          13948  1 dell_wmi
dell_laptop            18133  0 
dcdbas                 14928  1 dell_laptop
wmi                    19177  1 dell_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF1]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:77734305 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:77734305 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:5713765440 (5.7 GB)  TX bytes:5713765440 (5.7 GB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

##### resolv.conf #######################

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       834     1  0 11:56 ?        00:00:01 NetworkManager

##### NetworkManager info ###############

NetworkManager Tool

State: disconnected

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF1]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/GUPTA PROPERTY]] (600 root)
[connection] id=GUPTA PROPERTY | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=GUPTA PROPERTY | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/vivo Y51L]] (600 root)
[connection] id=vivo Y51L | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=vivo Y51L | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Neelu's iPhone]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Neelu's iPhone | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Neelu's iPhone | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Vijay]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Vijay | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Vijay | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Anjali jio]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Anjali jio | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Anjali jio | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Vipul Gulati]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Vipul Gulati | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Vipul Gulati | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MBLAZE-AC3633R2-2775]] (600 root)
[connection] id=MBLAZE-AC3633R2-2775 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=MBLAZE-AC3633R2-2775 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/WPJaipur]] (600 root)
[connection] id=WPJaipur | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=WPJaipur | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MBLAZE-AC3633R2-A6DE]] (600 root)
[connection] id=MBLAZE-AC3633R2-A6DE | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=MBLAZE-AC3633R2-A6DE | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/DIRECT-M6-BRAVIA]] (600 root)
[connection] id=DIRECT-M6-BRAVIA | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=DIRECT-M6-BRAVIA | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/edubot]] (600 root)
[connection] id=edubot | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=edubot | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Kunalâ€™s iPhone]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Kunalâ€™s iPhone | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=75;117;110;97;108;226;128;153;115;32;105;80;104;111;110;101; | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Classic mayur]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Classic mayur | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Classic mayur | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/dude]] (600 root)
[connection] id=dude | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=dude | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Royal Park]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Royal Park | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Royal Park | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/iris402+]] (600 root)
[connection] id=iris402+ | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=iris402+ | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Android ap]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Android ap | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Android ap | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Bsnl]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Bsnl | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Bsnl | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Le Royal Park]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Le Royal Park | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Le Royal Park | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MBLAZE-AC3633-5918]] (600 root)
[connection] id=MBLAZE-AC3633-5918 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=MBLAZE-AC3633-5918 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Harshit]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Harshit | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Harshit | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/rajmahal  roms]] (600 root)
[connection] id=rajmahal  roms | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=rajmahal  roms | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Advantage Homez F]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Advantage Homez F | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Advantage Homez F | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Diplomat]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Diplomat | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Diplomat | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/preferinn1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=preferinn1 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=preferinn1 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/JDS G*F]] (600 root)

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/TIARA]] (600 root)
[connection] id=TIARA | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=TIARA | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/The Forest]] (600 root)
[connection] id=The Forest | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=The Forest | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Blth-aHJpdGlrc2luZ2g5MTI]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Blth-aHJpdGlrc2luZ2g5MTI | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Blth-aHJpdGlrc2luZ2g5MTI | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/chaddas]] (600 root)
[connection] id=chaddas | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=chaddas | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Moto G (5) 7720]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Moto G (5) 7720 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Moto G (5) 7720 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/XT1033 2589]] (600 root)
[connection] id=XT1033 2589 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=XT1033 2589 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/3musketeers]] (600 root)
[connection] id=3musketeers | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=3musketeers | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Airtel-MW40-D027]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Airtel-MW40-D027 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Airtel-MW40-D027 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/XT1562 4102]] (600 root)
[connection] id=XT1562 4102 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=XT1562 4102 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/JDS S*F]] (600 root)

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Idea-Smartwifi-42a9]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Idea-Smartwifi-42a9 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Idea-Smartwifi-42a9 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Canon_ij_Setup]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Canon_ij_Setup | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Canon_ij_Setup | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ADYYMTAwTlU]] (600 root)
[connection] id=ADYYMTAwTlU | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=ADYYMTAwTlU | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/iamkhush]] (600 root)
[connection] id=iamkhush | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=iamkhush | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Ankush]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Ankush | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Ankush | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/BSNL_AP]] (600 root)
[connection] id=BSNL_AP | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=BSNL_AP | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/JioFi2_CA6674]] (600 root)
[connection] id=JioFi2_CA6674 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=JioFi2_CA6674 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/JioFi2_C5B034]] (600 root)
[connection] id=JioFi2_C5B034 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=JioFi2_C5B034 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Digisol]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Digisol | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Digisol | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Airtel_Zerotouch]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Airtel_Zerotouch | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Airtel_Zerotouch | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/AndroidAP]] (600 root)
[connection] id=AndroidAP | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=AndroidAP | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/thedude]] (600 root)
[connection] id=thedude | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=thedude | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ramesh wifi]] (600 root)
[connection] id=ramesh wifi | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=ramesh wifi | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Country Inn By carlson]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Country Inn By carlson | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Country Inn By carlson | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/NETGEAR]] (600 root)
[connection] id=NETGEAR | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=NETGEAR | bssid=<MAC address> | mac-address=9C:2A:70:CD:82:07
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Desi_Boys]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Desi_Boys | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Desi_Boys | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MotoG3 2783]] (600 root)
[connection] id=MotoG3 2783 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=MotoG3 2783 | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Kolkata (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (6, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 160), (6, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5250 - 5330 @ 160), (6, 20), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

##### module parameters #################

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF1]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# USB device 0x:0x (cdc_ether)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"
# PCI device 0x14e4:0x4365 (wl)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"
# USB device 0x:0x (cdc_ether)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth2"
# USB device 0x:0x (cdc_ether)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth3"

##### dmesg #############################

########## wireless info END ############
```

I havent checked ethernet, since I dont use it. 
I have tried `sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source`
and installed `bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu_amd64.deb' using offline mode.

Not sure how to proceed.

Edit 1:

```
$ sudo modprobe wl
modprobe: Fatal: Module wl not found
```

Edit 2:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package bcmwl-kernel-source.
(Reading database ... 242345 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2) ...
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.141+bdcom DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.13.0-129-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Module build for the currently running kernel was skipped since the
kernel source for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4.7) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-129-generic
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `sudo modprobe wl` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 added output

Comment: `bcmwl-kernel-source` is not installed. Install it again and post the output.

Comment: @Pilot6 added output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you removed headers for your kernel

Install these packages:

http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-3.13.0-129_3.13.0-129.178_all.deb

http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-3.13.0-129-generic_3.13.0-129.178_amd64.deb

Then re-install `bcmwl-kernel-source`

The Wi-Fi should start working, then run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

The system should be fixed.

And don't remove wrong packages any more.

Comment: Ok, Trying this. But just to understand, I have linux headers in /usr/src for 3.13.0-32 and 3.13.0-32-generic. As I can see my present version is 3.13.0-129-generic. So are you suggesting I removed them manually?

Comment: Yes, you removed them. Now the `wl` doesn't build. It is not a good idea to remove kernel packages this way. Use `autoremove`.

Comment: Okay I have installed all 3 packages, I can see wifi menus now, but it shows "Wifi disabled by hardware Switch" .

Comment: Also menu for "Enable Wifi" is also disabled

Comment: It is another issue. i suggest asking a new question. Post output of `rfkill list` there.

Comment: Every time software updater installs new updates , I have to download the 2 header files manually. How can I get this automatically, as it is supposed to happen.